# mysql 5.6.10: before update trigger only works with constant?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to get a trigger to update a row's value with a current timestamp and that same timestamp is being used in the table that is getting inserted on by this trigger. The trigger works with set new.last_update = 'some constant' , but the moment you add a variable or a select all I get is null values in the row.

```
drop trigger if exists event_update_history;
delimiter //
create trigger event_update_history before update on Events 
    for each row
    begin
        declare history_timestamp timestamp;
        set @history_timestamp = timestamp(unix_timestamp());
        if (new.current_state <> old.current_state) then
            insert into Event_History (evt_id, evt_state, time_of_change, userid) values (new.evt_id, new.current_state, history_timestamp, new.last_updated_by);
        end if;
        set new.last_update = history_timestamp; ## THIS IS THE PART THAT IS NOT WORKING but works if you send a constant
    end; //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Typo: You left out the `@` before `history_timestamp` in the `set` statement.

Comment: How your table is defined?  You can use default value for timestamp, and let MySQL to set it.

Comment: @Barmar, I think DeelThomson tried 2 things.  He have a variable named `history_timestamp`, and another one named `@history_timestamp`.  In the insert statement, he used `history_timestamp`.

Comment: Excellent! - Thank you kindly strangers. Though the @ sign was needed to init that variable for some reason - didn't know I was making two different ones. Makes way more sense now!

Comment: I guess what you're missing is that `history_timestamp` and `@history_timestamp` are two different variables.

Comment: Variables with `@` prefix are session variables, they don't need to be declared.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do:  `timestamp(unix_timestamp())`

```
mysql> select timestamp(unix_timestamp()), unix_timestamp();
+-----------------------------+------------------+
| timestamp(unix_timestamp()) | unix_timestamp() |
+-----------------------------+------------------+
| NULL                        |       1542320614 |
+-----------------------------+------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '1542320614' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

That is, since you are getting `NULL`, you think it is "not working".